# Why does the link to the market for log collector does not work?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I trying to include the LogCollector into my app and used the integration example from this site

http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/source/browse/trunk/android-log-collector-usage/src/com/xtralogic/android/logcollector/usage/Main.java

But when I try to use it in my app it shows correctly that its not installed

http://pbrd.co/VVD1Bx

But then it crashes while trying to open the marketplace, here is the log output

```
    01-10 20:38:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3265): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-10 20:38:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3265): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://search?q=pname:com.xtralogic.android.logcollector flg=0x10000000 }
    01-10 20:38:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
    01-10 20:38:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
    01-10 20:38:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
    01-10 20:38:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
    01-10 20:38:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at de.srs.android.pdixuploader.activies.SettingsActivity$1.onClick(SettingsActivity.java:102)
    01-10 20:38:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
    01-10 20:38:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-10 20:38:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    01-10 20:38:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    01-10 20:38:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-10 20:38:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    01-10 20:38:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    01-10 20:38:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    01-10 20:38:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What can be the reason for this? I am testing this on the emulator.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is because it is trying to open the applications page on Google Play, and the emulator does not have Google Play installed.

Therefore, there is no app to handle the `market://` URI scheme, resulting in an `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Your link will work find on a device that has Google Play installed. Keep in mind though that as of Android 4.2, LogCollector is no longer able to access other app's logs (or any other logging app for that matter, unless it has root permissions on a rooted device).

You can use the following method to check is the device has Google Play insatlled:

```
public boolean hasGooglePlayInstalled() {
    Intent market = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=dummy"));
    PackageManager manager = mContext.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = manager.queryIntentActivities(market, 0);

    if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).activityInfo.packageName.startsWith("com.android.vending") == true) {
                return true;
            }
        }
     }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The detection for google play works, but on my htc desire with android 2.2 a popup occurs with the title "Select an application to send the log" and with the message "This application cannot be executed with any application". Log Collector is installed on my device! Any hint?

Comment: @AlPhaba I haven't used log collector, so I can't really say. You could try contacting the developer(s) of the project. I believe they have a google group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/android-log-collector).